# Improving Fuzzy Logic Control System Results

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic

I am new to using skfuzzy and the use of fuzzy logic for classification, but the results I am getting are both good and bad for some conditions.  I am aware of the overarching impact the  defuzzification method (COA, BOA, MOM, SOM, LOM) has on deriving the defuzzied value, but I would like some advice on how others would approach this problem or what I have overlooked, which has thus caused outputs that don't exactly follow the rules I created.

**Fuzzy Model:**  I would like to rate a streams vulnerability to development based on distance from road and stream order (Strahler Hierarchy).  As the distance from a road to stream increases there will be less vulnerability (floating values from 0 m to 750 m).  On the other hand, as the Strahler order increases there will be a higher vulnerability because of more stream flow, stream width, habitat, etc. (Integer values from 1 to 10).

Vulnerability ranges from 0 to 1, with 0 being not vulnerable to 1 being very vulnerable.

```
# Antecedent/Consequent objects and membership functions
strmord = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(1, 11, 1), 'strmord')
strmdist = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 750, 1), 'strmdist')

# Defuzzification method:
# Fuzzy logic calculations are excellent tools, but to use them the fuzzy result must be 
# converted back into a single number. This is known as defuzzification.
# There are several possible methods for defuzzification:
# Centroid: 'centroid'
# Bisector: 'bisector'
# Mean of Maximum: 'mom'
# Min of Maximum: 'som'
# Max of Maximum: 'lom'

vul = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.05), 'vul', defuzzify_method='centroid')

# Custom membership functions for stream distance (in meters)
strmdist['low'] = fuzz.trimf(strmdist.universe, [0, 0, 150])
strmdist['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(strmdist.universe, [50, 150, 300])
strmdist['medhigh'] = fuzz.trimf(strmdist.universe, [200, 300, 450])
strmdist['high'] = fuzz.trimf(strmdist.universe, [350, 450, 550])
strmdist['vryhigh'] = fuzz.trimf(strmdist.universe, [450, 600, 750])

# Custom membership functions for Strahler Order
strmord['low'] = fuzz.trimf(strmord.universe,[1, 2, 3])
strmord['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(strmord.universe,[2, 3, 4])
strmord['medhigh'] = fuzz.trimf(strmord.universe, [3, 4, 5])
strmord['high'] = fuzz.trimf(strmord.universe, [4, 5, 6])
strmord['vryhigh'] = fuzz.sigmf(strmord.universe, 5.5, 10)

# Custom membership functions for vulnerability (0 to 1) 
vul['low'] = fuzz.trimf(vul.universe, [0, 0.15, 0.30])
vul['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(vul.universe, [0.15, .30, 0.5])
vul['medhigh'] = fuzz.trimf(vul.universe, [0.3, .5, 0.65])
vul['high'] = fuzz.trimf(vul.universe, [0.5, 0.65, 0.8])
vul['vryhigh'] = fuzz.trimf(vul.universe, [0.65, 0.80, 1.0])
```

Membership Functions:

[image]

```
# The Rules
# IF the distance is low and the strahler order is high, THEN the vulnerability will be high vul.
# IF the distance is low and the order is low THEN the vulnerability will be low.

rule1 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['low']|strmord['low'], vul['low'])
rule2 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medium']|strmord['low'], vul['low'])
rule3 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medhigh']|strmord['low'], vul['low'])
rule4 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['high']|strmord['low'], vul['low'])
rule5 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['vryhigh']|strmord['low'], vul['low'])

rule6 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['low']|strmord['medium'], vul['vryhigh'])
rule7 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medium']|strmord['medium'], vul['high'])
rule8 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medhigh']|strmord['medium'], vul['low'])
rule9 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['high']|strmord['medium'], vul['low'])
rule10 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['vryhigh']|strmord['medium'], vul['low'])

rule11 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['low']|strmord['medhigh'], vul['vryhigh'])
rule12 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medium']|strmord['medhigh'], vul['high'])
rule13 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medhigh']|strmord['medhigh'], vul['low'])
rule14 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['high']|strmord['medhigh'], vul['low'])
rule15 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['vryhigh']|strmord['medhigh'], vul['low'])

rule16 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['low']|strmord['high'], vul['vryhigh'])
rule17 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medium']|strmord['high'], vul['high'])
rule18 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medhigh']|strmord['high'], vul['medium'])
rule19 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['high']|strmord['high'], vul['low'])
rule20 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['vryhigh']|strmord['high'], vul['low'])

rule21 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['low']|strmord['vryhigh'], vul['vryhigh'])
rule22 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medium']|strmord['vryhigh'], vul['high'])
rule23 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['medhigh']|strmord['vryhigh'], vul['medium'])
rule24 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['high']|strmord['vryhigh'], vul['low'])
rule25 = ctrl.Rule(strmdist['vryhigh']|strmord['vryhigh'], vul['low'])

# Creation of control system using the defined rules 
vulnerability_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5, rule6, rule7, rule8, rule9, rule10,
    rule11, rule12, rule13, rule14, rule15, rule16, rule17, rule18, rule19, rule20, rule21, rule22, rule23, rule24, rule25])
    vulnerability = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(vulnerability_ctrl)
```

Test Cases:

```
# Testing of inputs
vulnerability.input['strmdist'] = some value
vulnerability.input['strmord'] = some value
vulnerability.compute()
print ('Vulerability Value: ', vulnerability.output['vul'])
vul.view(sim=vulnerability)
```

Some cases where the defuzzified values don't exactly align with the rules.  I used the centroid method for the following two cases:

1. When strmdist = 10 m and strmord = 1, the defuzzified value is ~0.50.  This should be a lower value.

[image]

2. When strmdist = 10 m and strmord = 5, the defuzzified value is ~0.50.  This should be a higher value.
   [image]
3. When I repeat #1 & 2 using the 'max of maximum method (lom)', I get a high value for both.

[image]

[image]